# How to upgrade lcov if you already have one in ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, lcov

I have lcov installed on my ubuntu 10.1. My lcov version is 1.8, how do I upgrade to the latest version, which is 1.9?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the .deb from Natty: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/lcov

Download and install it with:

```
wget http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/universe/l/lcov/lcov_1.9-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i lcov_1.9-2_all.deb
```

I did this on 10.04 LTS without any dependency-issues.